# How to improve parallel_bulk from python code for elastic insert?

Tags: python, performance, elasticsearch

I got some documents (size about `300o/doc`) that I'd like to insert in my ES index using the python lib, I got huge time difference between the code and using `curl` it's obvious that it's normal, but I'd like to know if time can be improved (compared to the ratio of time)

1. `curl` option takes about **20sec** to insert and whole time **10sec** (for printing ES result but after 20sec data is inserted)

   ```
   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST 
           "localhost:9200/contentindex/doc/_bulk?" --data-binary @superfile.bulk.json
   ```
2. With `python` option, I reached **1min20** as minimum, using the setting `10000/16/16` (`chunk/thread/queue`)

   ```
   import codecs
   from collections import deque
   from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
   from elasticsearch.helpers import parallel_bulk

   es = Elasticsearch()

   def insert_data(filename, indexname):
       with codecs.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as fic:
           for line in fic:        
               json_line = {}
               json_line["data1"] = "random_foo_bar1"
               json_line["data2"] = "random_foo_bar2"
               # more fields ...        
               yield {
                   "_index": indexname,
                   "_type": "doc",
                   "_source": json_line
               }

   if __name__ == '__main__':
    pb = parallel_bulk(es, insert_data("superfile.bulk.json", "contentindex"), 
                          chunk_size=10000, thread_count=16, queue_size=16)
    deque(pb, maxlen=0)
   ```

---

*Facts*

- I got a machine with *2 processors xeon 8-core* and *64GB ram*
- I tried multiple values for each `[100-50000]/[2-24]/[2-24]`

*Questions*

- Can I still improve the time ?
- If not, should I think of a way to write the data on a file and then use a process for `curl` command ?

---

If I try only the parse part it takes 15sec :

```
tm = time.time()
array = []

pb = insert_data("superfile.bulk.json", "contentindex") 
for p in pb:
   array.append(p)
print(time.time() - tm)            # 15

pb = parallel_bulk(es, array, chunk_size=10000, thread_count=16, queue_size=16)
dequeue(pb, maxlen = 0)
print(time.time() - tm)              # 90
```

Comment: Try to divide you app. To two parts, creating bulk and parallel_bulk. And share results with us.

Comment: @ozlevka  not sure to understand what you mean by the bulk part, my code is already divided in a generator and the parallel bulk

Comment: I mean separate a bulk data structure creation in memory from sending to elastic to point what from two parts is a bottleneck

Comment: @ozlevka done, edit and takes 15-20sec for parse part

Comment: And how much time take indexing?

Comment: @ozlevka About 1min now, I removed one part in the code that should not be taken into account

Comment: Could you please share the data file with us? I would like to test it on my environment. And last question: You have one machine or you run cluster?

Comment: @ozlevka  impossible for the data, I can just add that data is in fact 300o for each doc, 1m doc takes 300mo file when formatted as json/ only one node

Comment: How much docs you have in the file, and what one document size?

Comment: @ozlevka actually 1 million doc in 300MB file. But I have to think about a solution that could handle multiple GB file efficiently

Comment: Make sense. I will try and answer you. Elasticsearch has many configurations for touch...

Comment: I try to run the test and approach the same result... Curl working faster. I think it's a realization feature... Sorry for this. One advice, don't use 16 threads. My best approach was 8 threads and 10000 items chunk.  This is because of default Lucene threads. But this is configure parameter

Comment: I found great article about tuning index performance: https://qbox.io/blog/maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-1?utm_source=qbox.io&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-2 and https://qbox.io/blog/maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-2. Hope it's help you

Comment: @ozlevka I’ll read it and come back after ;)

Comment: @ozlevka if you want to write down a recap of your comments as an answer I’ll accept it and vote up. You helped me you deserve it ;)

Comment: I will... Thank you

Comment: @azro, It's rather late answer but, in ES documentation has been written that with bulk indexing a doc requires two lines: 1st is a operation metadata and 2nd is the doc itself. You use the same input file in both examples so I believe you should use only even lines from input in python examble. How many documents is in the index in each case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After my testing:

1. curl working more faster than python client, obviously curl implemented better.
2. After more testing and playing with parameters I can  conclude:

   1. Elasticsearch index performance depends on the configuration of the index and the entire cluster. You can approach more performance by right mapping of fields into the index.
   2. My best approach was on 8 threads and 10000 items chunk. This depends on the configuration of *index.index_concurrency* that 8 by default.
   3. I think that using the multinode cluster with separate master node should improve performance.
   4. For more information, you can read a great 2 part article I found: [here](https://qbox.io/blog/maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-1?utm_source=qbox.io&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-2) and [here](https://qbox.io/blog/maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-2)